# Remove leading commas from keys in object

Tags: javascript

Struggling to figure out how to remove leading commas from an keys in my object, so for example given this object:

```
{ 'D,F,': 14, 'G,,E': 32, ',D,R': 24 }
```

This is my desired end result

```
{ 'D,F,': 14, 'G,,E': 32, 'D,R': 24 }
```

Here is what I have tried

```
const newArr = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(sample).replaceAll('C', '').replaceAll(/(^[,\s]+)/g, '')
)
```

console.log(newArr)

and what I am getting

```
{ 'D,F,': 14, 'G,,E': 32, ',D,R': 24 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If your environment allows it you should use `Object.entries` and its opposite `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const sample = { 'D,F,': 14, 'G,,E': 32, ',D,R': 24 };

const transformed = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(sample).map(([key, value]) => [key.replace(/^,+/, ""), value])
);

console.log(transformed);
```

From MDN's page about `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`:

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs.

> The `Object.fromEntries()` method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.

After we get our pairs, we take each pair and remove the leading comma if any with `replace`, then take the transformed pairs and turn it back into an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use forEach to loop through all elements and find if any key is beginning with a comma.

```js
let json = { 'D,F,': 14, 'G,,E': 32, ',D,R': 24 };
let arr = []
Object.entries(json).forEach((element) => {
     if(element[0].charAt(0) == ','){
         let newKey = element[0].substring(1);
         arr[newKey] = element[1];
        }else {
            arr[element[0]] = element[1];
        }
    });
let newJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ ...arr }));
console.log(newJson);
```